# Copy text from clipboard, add text before and after clipboard content, then copy result back into clipboard

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to copy text from clipboard, add text before and after clipboard content, then copy result back into clipboard, but running into issues with formatting as the strings "begin" and "end" have mixtures of " and '

Im getting syntax errors: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

And not sure if im even coding this correctly...

```
    import pyperclip


    clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
    print=(clipboard_content)

    begin = curl -XPOST \ -H "Content-type: application/json" \ -d '{"alert": "


    end = "}' \ 'https:'


    command = 'begin' + 'clipboard_content' +  'end'


    print=(command)
    pyperclip.copy("command")
```

Comment: Your code fragment is not written in Python. It has numerous syntax errors. Too many to fix on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyperclip


clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
print(clipboard_content)


string1 = "curl -XPOST \\\n     -H "
string2 ='"Content-type: application/json" \\\n '
string3 = "    -d"
string4single= "'"
string5 = '{"alert": '
string6double = '"'
string7 = "}"
string8 = " \\"
string9 = "https:/"
string10 ="\n"
string11="       "

command = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4single + string5 + 
string6double + string10 + string10 + clipboard_content + string10 + string10 
+ string6double + string7 + string4single + string8 + string11 + string4single 
+ string9 + string4single

print(command)
pyperclip.copy(command)
```